# How to get the Value from a input field in QWebView

Tags: c++, qt, input, qwebview

In Qt I have a `QWebView` on the screen the site in the web view has an input field,
I want to get the **value** attribute from the input field and store it in a `QString`
Basically what I'm asking is how can I store the value of a input field in a `QString`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your QWebView get the QWebFrame (e.g `ui->webView()->page()->currentFrame()->toHtml();`) and then used [QwebFrame::findAllElements](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtwebkit/qwebframe.html#findAllElements) or [QWebFrame::findFirstElement](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtwebkit/qwebframe.html#findFirstElement). This will give you a [QWebElement](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtwebkit/qwebelement.html) and you can use the [attribute](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtwebkit/qwebelement.html#attribute) method to get the value attribute.

Answer (score 2):

You should use evaluateJavaScript("this.value") for dynamic get calues from attributes:
http://www.qtforum.org/article/34091/solved-get-html-dom-dynamic-value-via-qtwebview.html#post109395